# How to load a link in safari from a pdf being displayed in a UIWebView ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

```
I am using the Page View Application to show a series of PDF's. The UIWebView is displaying the PDF's fine, however whenever there is a link that is embedded into the PDF and the user clicks it, it opens the link inside of the UIWebView. I want it to open said link in safari.

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:page ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];


[self.webView loadRequest:request];

-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

As You can see i have tried to insert the code to launch it but the BOOL never gets run when stepped through.

Comment: did you checked other navigation types ?

Comment: Yes i have tried. Problem is i am not able to click the link in the pdf.
This code is working fine when i use a html file instead of pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:-

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked || inType ==UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked happens if the user taps a  style link, if the change is done from within Javascript (onclick event for example) UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther is used.

Furthermore UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther is used if you first load a page or you'll be redirected by a meta refresh or something

Comment: This code doesnot work. I have also tried to set the detector type but not able to click on the hyperlink in the pdf.    [self.webView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink];